# Raspberry Pi Docker: Trouble building kinesis video stream producer docker file on Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspian 11 Bullseye)

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am getting the below error when trying to use a Docker Image to build the kinesis video stream producer SDK on a Raspberry Pi:

[Command entered and Error Message Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzDHe.png)

I've followed the instructions to install the Docker Engine here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/raspbian/#installation-methods

I'm able to run the hello-world image which leads me to believe the Docker Engine was installed correctly. I looked into the folder to find there is no docker file but am unclear in which step I needed to put a file there or if it's expecting the file somewhere else.

I've tried uninstalling the older versions of packages and uninstalling the Docker Engine altogether. Thanks for the help!

Version:
[Raspian OS Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbpwa.png)
[Using 64-bit OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS0cL.png)

I tried uninstalling packages, updating, uninstalling Docker Engine, rebooting, and using specific versions.

I expected the producer library to be installed and to be able to run the gstreamer sample.

Comment: did you pull the arm image or the amd64 one?

Comment: @BeshoyHanna I pulled the amd64 one: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/. 

May have also tried the arm... : https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/raspbian/

Comment: no I mean the image itself in the docker container you are trying to run, is it arm or amd based?

Comment: @BeshoyHanna Got it. Sorry for my lack of knowledge but where would I find that out? I see this line in the docker file:
"RUN cmake .. -DBUILD_GSTREAMER_PLUGIN=ON -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_OPENSSL_PLATFORM=linux-armv4 && \
 make"

Does this mean the image itself that is in the container is arm based?

Comment: Not necessarily, you should check the FROM statements.